# Chrome Extension like Quicksilver/Gnome-Do?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, quicksilver

What are some Chrome extensions that provide keyboard-centric unified command prompt functionality in the style of Quicksilver for Mac or Gnome Do?

Bonus points for extensions that are most versatile and free-form.

Answer (score 1):

Ferro is a graphical predictive command line for Chrome commands, with a UI similar to Quicksilver. One difference is commands can appear in the left section if there are no arguments or the argument is the current tab or current tab's domain.

[Ferro: The Keyboard Interface to Chrome](http://www.getferro.com)